# QtCreator move text vertically shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

In Visual Studio, and other editors, you can move a line of text, or a block of code, using `alt`+ `up`/`down` arrow keys.
Is there a similar shortcut in QtCreator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally found the shortcut:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⬍</kbd>